# diffbot ros2_control_demos: how to configure output value for "hw_commands_"? Default output is 66.6666

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,  In the ros2_control_demos program: I test the (diffbot) diff-drive demo, and monitor the "hw_commands_"  variable, while I  publish the maximum val in  cmd_val  x = 1 this cause the value of "hw_commands_" is set to 66.0.

[image: image description]

The value of cmd_val is:
[image: image description]

I just wonder where the value is set? if we need to set this value where to set/configure it?  Please help.....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388561/diffbot-ros2_control_demos:-how-to-configure-output-value-for-%22hw_commands_%22?-default-output-is-66.6666/) by [shahrol.baharom](https://answers.ros.org/users/76634/shahrol.baharom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2021-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I guess that you are using some old version or publishing to a wrong topic, your velocity commands for DiffBot. Did you follow the exact manual from [here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos#diffbot)?

If you are using your custom command for publishing velocities, please check that the topic name is "/cmd_vel".

P.S. I will check the code one more time and have no idea where this value could come from. I am using "master"-branch.

EDIT:

I see that you are using foxy. We didn't backport the "master" functionality to Foxy, so if possible please use newest "Galactic" or "Rolling" version.

---

Originally posted by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) with karma: 877 on 2021-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0